# Any way to render fog on top of SSAO in three.js?

Tags: three.js, shader, post-processing

I'm using Fog and SSAO in my project, and the SSAO is emphasize stuff that needed to be faded, like the horizon line and buildings.
Is there any way the render the fog on top of the SSAO effect?
thanks.
[image]

I tried to write a shader, but it not working…

```
( function () {

var FogShader = {
    uniforms: {
        'tDiffuse': { value: null },
        'fogColor': {  value: new THREE.Vector3( 1.0, 0, 0 ) },
        'fogNear': {  value: 1.0 },
        'fogFar': {  value: 10.0 }
    },
    vertexShader:
    
    varying vec2 vUv;
    varying float fogDepth;
    
    void main() {

        vUv = uv;
        
        vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
        
        fogDepth = - mvPosition.z;
        

    }`,
    fragmentShader:
      `

    uniform vec3 fogColor;
    uniform float fogNear;
    uniform float fogFar;
    varying float fogDepth;
    
    uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {

        vec4 texel = texture2D( tDiffuse, vUv );
        gl_FragColor = texel ;
        
        float fogFactor = smoothstep( fogNear, fogFar, fogDepth );
        gl_FragColor.rgb = mix( gl_FragColor.rgb, fogColor, fogFactor );

    }`
};

THREE.FogShader = FogShader;

} )();
```

I’m using it like this:

```
var fogpass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.FogShader );
composer.addPass( fogpass );
```

If I manually change the fogFactor to 1 - all output is red, so I think I have something wrong with the fogDepth…

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate your fog formula in the SSAO shader. Then mix AO with fog:

```
float final = fog * multiplier * AO;
vec3 result = mix(scene, fognearcol * (1-fog), final);
```

Comment: It does not work, or I do something wrong, this is the shader I'm using:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/shaders/SSAOShader.js

Comment: You can add a combine pass, send scene color and fog parameters to it. Some keywords, "combine", "fogfactor", "tcolor".